# Buscador con palabras plurales/singulares

Tags: php, mysql

recién estoy programando una pagina web el cual tiene productos en electrónica.

Estoy implementando un buscador para encontrar los productos que el usuario ingrese.

Mi problema principal es que en mi BD en Mysql es por ejemplo:

> tengo agregado el producto Resistencia 100 ohm en la BD y cuando tecleo Resistencias(palabra en plural) no me devuelve el resultado,

---

> Si tecleo Resistencia(palabra singular) si me muestra resultados.

Mi consulta la estoy usando de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT nombre,precio,existencia,imagen,descripcion 
FROM partes 
WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%';
```

pd: tambien he intentado el `MATCH AGAINTS` y me encuentro con el mismo resultado

Answer (score 3):

puedes probar la funcion SOUNDEX de mysql:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre,precio,existencia,imagen,descripcion 
FROM partes 
WHERE soundex(nombre) LIKE soundex($busqueda)";
```

Incluso le puedes dar la vuelta:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre,precio,existencia,imagen,descripcion 
FROM partes 
WHERE soundex($busqueda) LIKE soundex(nombre)";
```

O buscar palabras parecidas dentro del campo:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre,precio,existencia,imagen,descripcion 
FROM partes 
WHERE soundex($busqueda) LIKE concat('%',soundex(nombre),'%')";
```

Dependiendo del campo mayor pondria uno delante del otro (siempre el menor detras).
Por ultimo te dejo un [enlace](https://database.guide/mysql-soundex-examples/) donde aprender mas sobre soundex 
Espero te sea util, un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias,voy a ver la documentacion y probare,y anunciare que tal fueron los resultados.

Answer (score 2):

El detalle es que el comodín `%` suple distintas funciones dependiendo de donde lo acomodes en tu valor a comparar

Caso 1 :Para este primer caso lo que estamos indicando es que busque dentro de la *tabla* todo donde el `producto` inicie con la cadena de texto resistencias así completa la palabra

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE producto LIKE "resistencias%";
```

Dado lo anterior si yo tengo una tabla con lo siguiente registrado

```
nombre
Resistencia de 100
Resistencias de 90
Limpiadores electronicos
Escobeta del 100
```

El único resultado que me devolverá será

```
nombre
Resistencias de 90
```

Caso 2: Si buscas obtener por ejemplo todos los registros cuyo nombre tenga dentro de si parte de la palabra resistencia, entonces tu búsqueda debería ser así

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE producto LIKE "resis%";
```

Lo anterior me dará como resultado

```
nombre
Resistencia de 100
Resistencias de 90
```

¿Por qué?

El uso del comodín al final de la cadena así `cadena%` hace o provoca que busque la coincidencia al inicio de la misma

En tu caso en particular al hacer lo siguiente

```
WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

No te va a devolver nada por que el uso del comodín tanto al inicio como al final lo que dice es:

> Donde el nombre sea como resistencias;

Es decir si la cadena que paso es `resistencias`, podemos comprobar que:

> La cadena resistencias es diferente de la cadena resistencia 100 ohm

```
"resistencias" <> "resistencia 100 omh"
```

Te pudieras auxiliar colocando mas de un comodín para establecer mas parámetros de búsqueda así

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE producto LIKE "resis%" OR nombre LIKE "%ohm";
```

Lo que le estoy diciendo es que me traiga todo de la tabla donde el producto inicie (por eso el comodín al final) con `resis` o donde el producto termine (por eso el operador al inicio) con `ohm`.

**Actualización**

Puedes valerte de [`FULLTEXT SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) que te va a permitir encontrar coincidencias en cadenas de texto mucho mas amplias y en cualquier parte de estas mismas, ejemplo:

Dentro del `CREATE TABLE` declaras a tu columna de la cual pretender encontrar coincidencias así:

```
FULLTEXT(nombreColumna)
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, puedes realizar tu búsqueda de este modo

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla 
WHERE MATCH(nombreColumna)
AGAINST("100", IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Si revisas, 100 es parte de tu cadena de texto pero no esta ni al inicio ni al final sino en medio de, con lo cual puedes ampliar tus procesos de búsqueda

Comment: Hola,muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en explicarme ese tipo de busqueda que estaba haciendo,me fue muy util. Sin embargo, en la pagina no solo tenemos productos resistencias,tambien son potenciadores,reguladores,transistores,etc... una cantidad grande de productos,por lo tanto lo que busco es una busqueda global donde me ayude con las coincidencias de busqueda cuando se escriban en plural

Comment: entiendo @IsaacD. sin embargo te dejo otra aproximación para atacar lo que tratas de hacer